# CXF Timeout not working

Tags: java, spring, web-services, weblogic, cxf

I created a web service client using cxf configured through Spring as shown below:

```
<!-- HTTP Conduit -->
<http-conf:conduit name="*.http-conduit">
    <http-conf:client ConnectionTimeout="30000"
        ReceiveTimeout="30000" />
</http-conf:conduit>

<!-- Client Proxies -->
<jaxws:client name="wsClient" serviceName="..."
    serviceClass="..."
    address="..." wsdlLocation="...">
</jaxws:client>
```

Now when the service is up, everything's working OK, But the problem is, when the service is down timeout values in the HTTPConduit are being ignored and I get the following error after 1 second:

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:570)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:479)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:382)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:335)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:136)

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Tried all: '1' addresses, but could not connect over HTTP to server: '192.168.80.55', port: '24004'
at weblogic.net.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:333)
at weblogic.net.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:425)
at weblogic.net.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:252)
at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:213)
at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:279)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPCon2014-08-30 13:06:59 ERROR: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not send Message.
```

Any clue why the consumer doesn't stay for the timeout duration before raising this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timeout does not apply when the server is 'down'.

The `ConnectionTimeout` is how much to wait before connecting.

The `ReceiveTimeout` is how much to wait before receving a response.

In your case, there is no server listening on that port, so when your clients try to connect, the clients fails **immediatly**.